# Why leaflet map tiles ordering wrong

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to render a map with a popular visualization coordinate system,
but the map tile is wrong ordering. 
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    // crs: crs,
    continuousWorld: true,
    worldCopyJump: false,
    zoomControl: true
});

new L.TileLayer('https://www.gtrack.co.id/TileMapService/TileMap.ashx?cachetype=0&tilex={x}&tiley={y}&level={z}', {
    maxZoom: 14,
    minZoom: 0,
    continuousWorld: true,
    tileSize:256,
    // tms: true
}).addTo(map);

map.setView([-0.497125, 117.108078], 5);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't with the tileserver? I tried using the link but it doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: @JoostK, Yes Im sure, the link have used before with Google API, and the map shown normally

Comment: you could try switching z and y I could see some providers implementing this different

Comment: I added some property to tile layer, the map ordering correctly
but the center of map isn't accurate,


var map = L.map('map', {
 // crs: crs,
 continuousWorld: true,
 worldCopyJump: false,
 zoomControl: true,
 crs: L.CRS.Simple
});

new L.TileLayer('https://www.gtrack.co.id/TileMapService/TileMap.ashx?cachetype=0&tilex={x}&tiley={y}&level={z}', {
 maxZoom: 14,
 minZoom: 0,
 continuousWorld: true,
 tileSize:256,
 // bounds: [[-5200, -5200], [5200, 5200]],
 // tms: true
}).addTo(map);

map.setView([-0.497125, 117.108078], 5);

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the Z index for the tile server is not zero-based like `TileLayer([x,y], z)` expects to receive. You have to pass an argument called `zoomOffset` with value 1 to fix this.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    // crs: crs,
    continuousWorld: true,
    worldCopyJump: false,
    zoomControl: true
});

new L.TileLayer('https://www.gtrack.co.id/TileMapService/TileMap.ashx?cachetype=0&tilex={x}&tiley={y}&level={z}', {
    maxZoom: 14,
    minZoom: 0,
    continuousWorld: true,
    tileSize:256,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    zoomOffset: 1 // <------------ the param to add
}).addTo(map);

map.setView([-0.497125, 117.108078], 5);
```

Then you get:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with invalid, empty and misplaced placed tiles as well.

As I do not know the service you are requesting the tiles from, this solution may not apply to you, but this might help any passerby using OpenStreetMaps:

In the URL, **x**, **y** and **z** must **NOT** be in alphabetical order like so:

```
const tileURL = "https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{x}/{y}/{z}.png";
```

but must instead be **in this order**>:

```
const tileURL = "https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
```

Otherwise, invalid tiles will be requested, resulting in an unusable, faulty map.